# How to Set Alert Type Based on Model?

Tags: vuetify.js

I want to set the type of alert based on model; however, I couldn't find an example.

I tried to do it like this inside `v-alert`:

```
<v-alert v-model="alert"
         type="result === true ? success : warning">
  <span> {{message}} </span> 
</v-alert>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simple example of what you probably need [Code Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zQYpyO?&editable=true&editors=101)

```
<v-alert :value="true" :type="result ? 'success' : 'warning'">
```

and

```
data(){
    return {
      result: true
    }
}
```

Also, take a look on [Vue Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html)